# When using SSRS is there a way I can get an outside column to show up next to a specific inside matrix column

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm working on a report and the person needs it to be presented in a specific way. I'm not sure how to get my columns from the outside that are displaying dates to be next to a column inside the matrix that is displaying values.

For example it is setup like this:

```
     |   HiredDt   |  TermDt  |         [Type]         |   LicDt   |    MedDt   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID   |  [HiredDt]  | [TermDt] |  SUM([Count_of_Type])  |  [LicDt]  |   [MedDt]  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And looks like this:

```
     |   HiredDt   |  TermDt  |   Lic   |   Med   |   App   |     LicDt   |    MedDt   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |  1/31/12    | 1/31/14  |    1    |    1    |    12   |    6/1/15   |   9/1/14   |
2    |  2/19/12    | 9/18/14  |    1    |    1    |    12   |    3/2/15   |   9/1/14   |
```

What I'm trying to get would look like this:

```
     |   HiredDt   |  TermDt  |   Lic   |   LicDt   |   Med   |   MedDt   |    App   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |  1/31/12    | 1/31/14  |    1    |   6/1/15  |    1    |  9/1/14   |     12   |
2    |  2/19/12    | 9/18/14  |    1    |   3/2/15  |    1    |  9/1/14   |     12   |
```

Is this even possible to make happen? I'm quite new to SSRS so I may not have put everything into great terms, but I feel like I showed an example well enough to describe my issue.

Comment: When you are in a context or either 'row' or 'column' (Matrix has both).  You can click on the lowest level and right click and get a context menu.  Select 'Inside Group (Left/Right)' to be in the scope you are in, else it will be outside that scope and on the parent level.  In your lower pane you should see 'Row Groups' and 'Column Groups' to let you know where you are in the leveling.

Comment: @djangojazz This works for one but not both. Is there a way I can get both of the dates to be side by side with the columns inside the matrix?

Comment: Just ensure you are on that level and you can add as many columns or rows that you want.  Just keep in mind each one of these rows that is NOT the detail row(lowest level) will have a Key that it pivots on to be the 'grouping'.  If you are doing something on a parent level and there is more than one date, then you have to show a (max, min, avg, etc) because you are combining multiple objects in a single place.

Comment: @djangojazz Well now the issue i'm running into is that because i add a column under the group it is creating a lot of white space on columns that aren't associated with the dates column and there is no way for me to title the column of the dates since they are inner group columns